# Sort by value based on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

This is a query from Wordpress, but applies to any database setup this way.  They have some data stored in meta fields.  There is a table that has two fields called meta_name and meta_value.  These fields are used to store almost everything.  For instance, meta_name could be "lastname" and meta_value is the value of that name.  I have a query that will return all users, but how can I sort by meta_value when meta_name="lastname"?  Below is the current query.

```
SELECT um.user_id, users.display_name, GROUP_CONCAT(um.meta_value SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` um, `wp_7bv88z_pmpro_memberships_users` u, `wp_7bv88z_users` users 
WHERE u.user_id=um.user_id and users.ID=u.user_id and (um.meta_key='pmpro_sfirstname' or um.meta_key='pmpro_slastname') 
and u.status='active'
GROUP BY um.user_id
```

Sample Data:

user_meta table

```
╔════=====╦══════════════==╦══════=======╗
║ user_id ║  meta_key        ║ meta_value  ║
╠════=====╬══════════════==╬══════=======╣
║  1      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Jeff        ║
║  1      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Atwood      ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Geoff       ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Davis       ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Jarrod      ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Minor       ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Joel        ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Brown       ║
╚════=====╩════════════=====╩══════======╝
```

Expected Results:

```
1, Jeff Atwood
4, Joel Brown
2, Geoff Davis
3, Jarrod Minor
```

Comment: show us sample data and expected results.

Comment: `SELECT um.user_id, users.display_name.... GROUP BY um.user_id` is are misusing MySQL's GROUP BY feature which will result in invalid results. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ ... Besides you are using the comma join syntax which is hard to read and maintain and very old syntax what is over 25 years old. Use normal `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax instead.

Comment: Yes, I realize it is older syntax.  I was using GROUP BY so I could combine the firstname and lastname on the same row.  I have added sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of old syntax or cross joins - but you could do something like this;

```
SELECT um.user_id, 
       users.display_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(um.meta_value SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM `user_meta` um, 
      `memberships_users` u, 
      `users` users,
      `user_meta` lname,
      `user_meta` fname
WHERE u.user_id = um.user_id 
      and users.id = u.user_id 
      and (lname.user_id = u.user_id and lname.meta_key = 'pmpro_slastname')
      and (fname.user_id = u.user_id and fname.meta_key = 'pmpro_sfirstname')
      and (um.meta_key='pmpro_sfirstname' or um.meta_key='pmpro_slastname') 
and   u.status='active'
GROUP BY lname.meta_value, fname.meta_value, um.user_id
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8b0e6/5) to see it in action